# Converting CIImage to UIImage returns black image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to change perspective in image, using core image and CIFilter. But after convert CIImage to UIImage, my image is black.

```
    let perspectiveTransform = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveTransform")!
    let composite = CIFilter(name: "CISourceAtopCompositing")!
    let backgroundImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "interior0.jpg")!)!
    let clearImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "clear.png")!)!
    perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIVector(x: CGFloat(perspectiveValues["inputTopLeftVectorX"]!), y: CGFloat(perspectiveValues["inputTopLeftVectorY"]!)),
                                  forKey: "inputTopLeft")
    perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIVector(x: CGFloat(perspectiveValues["inputTopRightVectorX"]!), y: CGFloat(perspectiveValues["inputTopRightVectorY"]!)),
                                  forKey: "inputTopRight")
    perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIVector(x: CGFloat(perspectiveValues["inputBottomRightVectorX"]!), y: CGFloat(perspectiveValues["inputBottomRightVectorY"]!)),
                                  forKey: "inputBottomRight")
    perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIVector(x: CGFloat(perspectiveValues["inputBottomLeftVectorX"]!), y: CGFloat(perspectiveValues["inputBottomLeftVectorY"]!)),
                                  forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
    perspectiveTransform.setValue(CIImage(image: (imageView?.image)!),
                                  forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let topImage = UIImage(CIImage: backgroundImage)
```

And when I set `topImage` to `imageView?.image`, then it shows black image.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Render your `CIImage` into a `CGImage` and create the `UIImage` from that

Comment: I did like this 
        let cgimg = softwareContext.createCGImage(perspectiveTransform.outputImage!, fromRect:perspectiveTransform.outputImage!.extent)
        imageView?.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)
And still didn't work

Comment: I forget to add. On Mac iPad simulator everything looks nice but on real device it is black image.